# Docker run not working it says requires at least 1 argument

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker, and trying to run the existing images. The first command is working fine

`command 1: docker run --name static-site -e AUTHOR="Mathi1" -d -P dockersamples/static-site`

But the below command is throwing error

`Command 2: docker run --name mvcdotnet -e AUTHOR="Mathi2" -d -p valkyrion/mvcdotnet`

Error:

> "docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
>
> See 'docker run --help'.
>
> Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
>
> Run a command in a new container

Comment: By the way valkyrion/mvcdotnet is not my repository, and docker run -d valkyrion/mvcdotnet is wrking fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `docker help run`:

```
…
-p, --publish list                   Publish a container's port(s) to the host
-P, --publish-all                    Publish all exposed ports to random ports
…
```

Command 1 uses `-P` (short form of `--publish-all`) and after that the image name. `-P` has no arguments.
Command 2 uses `-p` (short form of `--publish list`). `-p` expects an argument and I think docker mistakes the image name as the argument for `-p` (and expects an image name after that).

Comment: Thanks for the help stefan. It was a case sensitive issue. I should have used caps "P". Its working fine now