# Docker MySQL: "docker run" requires at least 1 argument

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, containers, mysql-8.0

I'm following this [guide](https://medium.com/@crmcmullen/how-to-run-mysql-in-a-docker-container-on-macos-with-persistent-local-data-58b89aec496a) to use MySQL 8.0 in Docker (on macOS host), but I'm having some issues. I have no Docker experience other than this, so please be easy on me. I tried to debug as best I could. It seems the author of the guide has some outdated commands/syntax errors (not sure which), which I think I've fixed. However, when I try to run the following command, I keep getting the error below:

Command:

```
docker run --restart always --name mysql8.0 --network dev-network -v /Users/[my-name]/mysql/data/8.0:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3308 -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[my-password] mysql:8.0
```

( `[my-name]` and `[my-password]` are subbed out).

Error:
`"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.`

I've checked `docker run --help` but can't get any further.

I've also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308424/docker-container-run-requires-at-least-1-argument) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041231/docker-run-not-working-it-says-requires-at-least-1-argument), but those cases seem highly specific to the OPs' situation, so the answers didn't yield any successful results for me.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: That image has its own perfect actual explanation on how to use it: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: There might be some special characters in your password that are ending up confusing the parser? In which case putting single quotes around MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[my-password] might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you've pasted works fine. There is a possibility that the password you're entering has some special characters making the shell think of it as something else. (Or your volume next to -v flag has some special characters).

Just to test, try with a simple password like this:

```
docker run --restart always --name mysql8.0 --network dev-network -v /Users/[yourusername]/mysql/data/8.0:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3308 -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testpass
```

mysql:8.0

Comment: Yep, sure enough that was it! Thank you! It looks like the password accepts alphanumeric characters only.